# Understanding Java as a Delphi programmer

Tags: java, delphi, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I have a database I have created in Delphi that’s still in the testing phase
I found it easy to give access to my database through Java in the form of a *.dll
but this is not just a standard database (its very cutting edge with Nodes).
It’s taken me a lot of learning to get to this point. I very much appreciate the help and thanks of this forum and the replies I have received to my questions to get me hear.

What it very exciting at the moment is Android devices and to write in java
But I know nearly nothing about Java. The developers are like five times more busy than Delphi. The Google apps web page is averaging about 40 hits a day and thats only a part of java.
I want to make it accessible to the Maven approach to using databases that I have no documentation on how to do this yet.

I know I have ShortIntegers, LongIntegers, I'm not sure about strings that originate as ANSCI but can be UTRF-8 and other things. Do I have double numbers and do I have date records.

Do I have any other type data types in java

Can any one enlighten me please.

Comment: You'll certainly see parellels with Delphi as you learn Java, but the syntax is different enough that you should just pick up a beginner's Java book and familiarize yourself with the different syntax and APIs.

Comment: lexdean? Is this your tenth account here?

Answer (score 3):

[Java for dummies](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470087161)

Answer (score 2):

If you are Delphi programmer then you you know how to program: you know loops, routines, variables, objects etc. Java differs from Delphi in many things, but it is hard to say what will make problems to you. You must give it a try.

1. Install JDK
2. Read some good Java book. You can find some good free books such as older edition of [Thinking in Java](http://mindview.net/Books/TIJ/)
3. Fire good text editor. You can start with Eclipse or Netbeans, but there are many simple editors with Java syntax highlighting that may be better for Java novice
4. Start writing programs in Java.

Comment: 'Fire good text editor' - LOL, how many of us Delphi developers wrote their first Delphi app with Notepad? :)

Comment: mjustin, you got me :) For Pascal/Delphi I started with Turbo Pascal IDE, but now I sometimes use Edit+ or Context to edit .pas files. Newest IDEs start very slooow :)

Comment: IDE as we know it today are very helpful. They hide some "boring" details. But then for IDE-only developers environment without IDE, with only command line tools from JDK is "black magic".