# Going from Delphi to java guide?

Tags: java, delphi, programming-languages

I am wondering is there something like a little guide or tutorial for a programmer who has experience in delphi and wants to learn java? Like a syntax guide etc

I've been using delphi since I was about 13 years old as it was taught in high school. I am now 19. I have become very fond of delphi and how simple it is :)

Also if anyone has any good links for netbeans tutorials for beginners I would appreciate them as well :)

Comment: This question should really be moved to [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: And is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851736/understanding-java-as-a-delphi-programmer)

Comment: oh thanks charles! That should help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just google "java delphi comparison" and it will turn up a lot of helpful pages.  I couldn't find the document I remember from seven or eight years ago, but here are a few directly on topic:

http://www.sheetudeep.com/res/javadev/ch5.htm

http://www.scribd.com/doc/51732218/Comparing-OO-Features-of-Delphi-C-C-Java

http://delphi.about.com/gi/o.htm?zi=1/XJ&zTi=1&sdn=delphi&cdn=compute&tm=18&f=10&su=p284.9.336.ip_p504.1.336.ip_&tt=2&bt=1&bts=0&zu=http%3A//www.marcocantu.com/papers/ooplang.htm